# How does arena matchmaking work in Angry Birds 2?

Tags: angry-birds-2

Been playing this for a few weeks now and I'm seeing some really unexpected opponents popping up in the AB2 arena.  So I started wondering how the matchmaking works. Is it live, or am I playing someone else's persona, or what?

I'm inclined to believe the latter. I mean, the gear choices for my opponents seem totally random. E.g. some players have a bronze slingshot but half their birds have no hats on. Also during a match I sometimes see them having two of the same card (eg 2x chuck) lined up, which should be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that your opponents slingshot always matches yours, which seems to make upgrading slingshots bad almost.  The games arent live as the matches have no time limit and your opponent cant watch a video or pay gems to get additional birds.
I assume that the opponents score is representative of a previous arena match they played.  I believe thats why their spells will show up on the prematch screen before you can select spells to use.

Answer (score -1):

Since the last update, around 9/15, the matchmaking has apparently changed. While before, it would normally match you up with players at a similar level, now, after you reach the 3rd win, it will match you with players that are twice your level, making it impossible to win unless you use multiple extra cards and gems.